# Audio Queue Interface can deal with 40ms Audio Frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audioqueue, audioqueueservices

I am trying to record the audio in segment of 40ms. 
Audio Queue Interface can deal with 40ms Audio Frame? 
If 'Yes' then how can we achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, its possible , you need to set configure AudioQueue Accordingly,

Basically the AudioQueue Buffer size, has to be set for 40ms, so it would be around,

```
int AQRecorder::ComputeRecordBufferSize(const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format, float seconds)
{
    int packets, frames, bytes = 0;
    try {
        frames = (int)ceil(seconds * format->mSampleRate);

        if (format->mBytesPerFrame > 0)
            bytes = frames * format->mBytesPerFrame;
        else {
            UInt32 maxPacketSize;
            if (format->mBytesPerPacket > 0)
                maxPacketSize = format->mBytesPerPacket;    // constant packet size
            else {
                UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
                XThrowIfError(AudioQueueGetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MaximumOutputPacketSize, &maxPacketSize,
                                                    &propertySize), "couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size");
            }
            if (format->mFramesPerPacket > 0)
                packets = frames / format->mFramesPerPacket;
            else
                packets = frames;   // worst-case scenario: 1 frame in a packet
            if (packets == 0)       // sanity check
                packets = 1;
            bytes = packets * maxPacketSize;
        }
    } catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        return 0;
    }   
    return bytes;
}
```

and to set the format,

```
void AQRecorder::SetupAudioFormat(UInt32 inFormatID)
{
    AudioStreamBasicDescription sRecordFormat;
    FillOutASBDForLPCM (sRecordFormat,
                        SAMPLING_RATE,
                        1,
                        8*BYTES_PER_PACKET,
                        8*BYTES_PER_PACKET,
                        false,
                        false
                        );
    memset(&mRecordFormat, 0, sizeof(mRecordFormat));

    mRecordFormat.SetFrom(sRecordFormat);
}
```

for my case, values of these Macros are,

```
#define SAMPLING_RATE 16000
#define kNumberRecordBuffers    3
#define BYTES_PER_PACKET 2
```

Comment: Hi Rohan,

Thanks for your response,

I have changed the project accordingly and it's working at my end. As I am new to this field, How can I make sure that it is working at 40ms audio frame per packet?

Thanks, Pravin

Comment: AudioQueue framework, throws a callback when the enqueued buffer is filled, so the minimum interval would be 40ms for sure...

Comment: Thanks Rohan, Can you please give me idea (formula) about 40ms audio frame per packet calculation with respect to Macros/Define i.e. SAMPLING_RATE, kNumberRecordBuffers, BYTES_PER_PACKET

Comment: in the above function just pass float secods = .04

Comment: @Amitg2k12 where and how to pass and use  float secods = .04

Comment: @Naresh in the function AQRecorder::ComputeRecordBufferSize(const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format, float seconds) , 2nd parameter should be .04

Comment: Hello, currently I used this function to compute the buffer size for 30ms, sample rate 8000 and 16 bits, and I get 480 for the buffer size. It's correct. But I will get many callback to fill in the buffer with 30 ms? Why? Why not just one buffer within 30 ms? Thanks

Comment: @ Ecro : AudioQueue callback will hit asynchronously to get the buffer as and when audio queue needed, normally audioQueue request once in a while for most of time,